# Android app crashes and returns to menu and then works

Tags: android, crash

I'm writing a app with some info on ingress. This is my first app so i'm kinda new to android.

I have a menu which consist of 8 buttons. For one of them it opens a activity that has two imagebuttons. Each imagebutton opens a different activity that has only a textview in it.

My problem is this. When I first run the app it crashes if i hit either of the image buttons. it then returns to the menu. If i go back to either imagebutton, now it works.

I'm running my app on a GS4 running 4.2.2 debugging it gave me the error source not found. not sure whats wrong.

the class with the two buttons

```
public class Factions extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageButton resis, enligh;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_factions);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    resis = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibResistance);
    resis.setOnClickListener(this);

    enligh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibEnlightened);
    enligh.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.factions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibEnlightened:
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutEnlightened.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.ibResistance:
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutResistance.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

the xml for that class

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibResistance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/resistance_logo_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibEnlightened"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/enlightened_logo_button" />
```

the class for the two textviews only have the onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu methods. i don't need to change them or add anything to it. If you need any other info let me know. Thanks in advance.

the logcat shows this

```
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3460)     08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:446) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at com.kaveman.ingress.faqs.AboutResistance.onCreate(AboutResistance.java:12) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: I/dalvikvm(11028):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.541: D/skia(11028): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap 
08-09 22:07:00.541: D/AndroidRuntime(11028): Shutting down VM 
08-09 22:07:00.541: W/dalvikvm(11028): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41173ac8) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kaveman.ingress.faqs/com.kaveman.ingress.faqs.AboutResistance}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at com.kaveman.ingress.faqs.AboutResistance.onCreate(AboutResistance.java:12) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    ... 11 more 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    ... 23 more 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3460) 08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:446) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172) 
08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to load a very large bitmap and running out of memory. Perhaps there might be useful information on this page and its sub-pages: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the line you should be interested in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 08-09 22:07:00.571: E/AndroidRuntime(11028):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

Are you using an android virtual device? Try increasing the VM in the Virtual Device Manager.